# Python en Eclipse PyDev, ventanas

Tags: python, eclipse

Despues de configurar eclipse para python, al intentar correr un codigo que usa ventanas, el mismo no me muestra las ventanas,

```
print ('hola')
from tkinter import *
from math import *
#import tkinter
ventana=Tk()


ventana.title('Calculadora')
ventana.geometry('392x600')
salida=Entry(ventana,font=('arial',20,'bold'),width=22,bd=20,insertwidth=4,bg='powder blue',justify='right').place(x=10, y=60)

ancho_boton=11
alto_boton=3

boton_0=Button(ventana,text='0',width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton).place(x=17,y=180)
boton_1=Button(ventana,text='1',width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton).place(x=107,y=180)
boton_2=Button(ventana,text='2',width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton).place(x=197,y=180)
boton_3=Button(ventana,text='3',width=ancho_boton,height=alto_boton).place(x=287,y=180)
```

Comment: Rubén, bienvenido. ¿Podrías indicar el error que estás recibiendo, por favor?

Comment: El codigo esta bien el problema que tengo es que al correrlo no se ejecutan las ventanas. Probe el mismo codigo en el Thonny y mecorre bien.

Comment: Prueba poniendo esto en la última línea:**ventana.mainloop()**. Creo que en realidad la ventana se abre y se cierra solá al no tener el mainloop que la mantenga en ese estado.

Comment: BINGO, si hermano efectivamente se cerraba sola,  hay alguna otra forma de evitar que se cierre?

Comment: otra consulta, si voy a trabajar con librerias donde puedo documentar en el manejo de ellas?